# gcloud create instance gives "The billing account is not in good standing; therefore no new instance can be created."

Tags: google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I'm writing a script to initiate an google cloud sql database:

```
gcloud sql instances create sql_testcustomer --region europe-west1 --tier D1 --quiet
```

but it gives me the following errors:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.create) ResponseError: status=403, code=Forbidden, reason=invalidBillingAccountState
message=The billing account is not in good standing; therefore no new instance can be created.
```

Needless to say I've googled it extensively without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is error message has nothing to do with billing, but instead it's because the sql instance name cannot have "_" in them. Replacing the instance name from "sql_testcustomer" to "sql-testcustomer" solves this issue.

Comment: I also noticed something similar that's not related billing. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error while trying to create a Postgres instance with Terraform. Eventually I figured out that it was because I hadn't set the project ID for the instance, which should just default to the default project, but instead was throwing an error.